# Найти <li> с определенным текстом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет.

Есть код:

```
var ex = $('.ex-ul').find( $('.ex-li').text( $('.input').val() ));
```

Но в `ex` записывается `[object Object]`.
Как правильно найти элемент по содержимому?

Comment: Что такое **ex-ul**? У вас есть такой селектор?

Comment: `но в ex записывается [object Object] как верно подскажите` - логично, вы ж туда и кладете некий jquery объект

Comment: да селектор просто тут без переменных написал что бы не писать что значат переменные а из нзхвания селектора понятно

Comment: Покажите ваш HTML и напишите то, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: ну я хочу найти в списке элемент который равен содержимому `.input`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вам нужен **[contains](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83)** - соответствует элементам, которые содержат строку *text* :

```js
$('div:contains("тест")').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Петр</div>
<div>тест</div>
<div>кто-то еще</div>
```

---

Для точного совпадения по слову можно использовать **[filter](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)**. Он фильтрует набор выбранных элементов по заданному критерию:

```js
var str = 'тест';
var elements = $("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === str;
}).css('border', '1px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Петр</div>
<div>тест</div>
<div>кто-то еще</div>
<div>тампарам</div>
<div>тест</div>
<div>тест222</div>
```

Comment: @Санитариум `var ex = $('.ex-ul:contains("' + $('.input').val() + '"');`

Comment: Не совсем то.Мне надо точно совпадение.

Comment: @Санитариум Добавил в ответ вариант

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась топорно: перебором в цикле.

```
$.each($('.ex-li'), function (index, value) 
{
  if (val != element.text()) 
  {
    //что то делаем
  }
});
```